# Cassandra: when to add capacity?

Tags: cassandra

How does one know when it's time to add capacity to a cassandra cluster? Error msgs? Performance? Some other tell-tale sign?

Since capacity planning with Cassandra is a (seemingly) black art knowing where to start and when to grow could be somewhat problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing anything about your workload, I'd start looking at:

- IO queue length
- CPU load
- Amount of data read vs written
- GC behavior
- Compaction stats

When any of these start to get "high" (definition depends on your hardware) then it's time to revisit your application, or scale up.